# Image picker controller allows editing doesn't crop or edit the photo

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiimagepickercontroller, photo

I use allows editing method put it doesn't work is there any other methods that I can use for that purpose, when I select the photo it stick in the middle no matter what I do

```
    func selectProfileImage() {
            let pickerController = UIImagePickerController()
            pickerController.delegate = self
            PiActivityIndicator.startAnimating()
            pickerController.allowsEditing = true
            present(pickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)

        } 

extension SignupVC: UINavigationControllerDelegate,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

        if let image = info["UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"] as? UIImage {
            selectedImage = image
            profileImage.image = image


        }
        self.PiActivityIndicator.stopAnimating()

        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Where's your implementation of the image picker delegate method?

Comment: if you want me to put the rest of my code tell me

Comment: Never use `"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"`. Use the provided key of `UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage` (note the lack of quotes). Now please read the documentation for that key and the other related keys. What do you notice? BTW - I'm trying to help you find your own answer here, I'm not trying to be difficult. Please keep that in mind here.

Comment: you mark it as duplicated question I never seen no answer to this question if i get the answer i wold not ask now can you answer my question with code

Comment: Did you read the answer to the duplicate question I linked? It tells you exactly what you need to do.

Comment: ok thank you i got it look what do i do know delete my question or leave it so people can finde it